# Customise default snooze time in Gmail 2018?

Tags: gmail

Currently always defaults to 08:00 AM, is it possible to adjust this time to always say something like 06:00, for instance?

[image]

Comment: Please unaccept the currently accepted answer, as it is o longer valid, and accept the other one. (This is according to the site's policy.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To customize the snooze times go to [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/u/0/) in the same account, open Settings (gear icon at the top right), and edit the times from there. Verified working with G Suite as well. Make sure to reopen your Gmail tab after saving the settings.

[image: Google Keep settings screenshot]

Comment: Didn't work on my GMail account :(

Comment: Did you make sure to save? Have you refreshed / reopened the Gmail tab afterwards?

Comment: I made the changes, then reloaded my gmail tab.  Change didn't take effect.

Comment: Didn't work on mine either.  Made change, saved, then reloaded gmail in Chrome web browser.  Snooze time unchanged.  Tried again.  This time hit Shift Return to reload without using cache.

Comment: I managed to sneak in the update to Inbox before they turned it off :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't let you "Set your weekend" like Inbox did :(

Comment: It works for me perfectly.

Comment: I've confirmed that as of Android 9 on Pixel 3, this setting isn't editable in the GMail Android app, unlike iOS app, per Neil's answer above. Of course, the Keep app could be used for that on Android, but again, that's an awkward flow. I use GSuite, so your mileage may vary on all of these findings. I suspect the "Next weekend" option is for consumer accounts and doesn't make as much sense for GSuite, as most reminders would be desired for work weekdays. +1 to the comment from davidvandebunte above about not being able to customize weekends, though. I'd say a more general custom snooze would

Comment: I'd say a more general custom snooze would meet that need and others. [I'll be logging some feedback for the GSuite team including all of these comments and a link to this post](https://www.cloudconnectcommunity.com/ccc/ls/community/g-suite/post/6311424599261184) to ask them to improve the snooze feature by cross-pollinating with Keep and bring back some of the good Inbox features. I'd encourage others to do the same, per Ray Foss's comment above. Hopefully I added something to the conversation. Thanks for reading!

Comment: This works for me on Android. I would love to see the feature for adding more defaults than the current three options.

Answer (score 10):

It's not very intuitive - it can be changed from [Inbox](https://inbox.google.com/), not from [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/), I think it's because the snooze feature is new in Gmail and they didn't renew the settings section yet.

**So from Inbox:**

- Open Inbox **⚙ Settings** (At the bottom of all labels)
- Go to Snooze tab
- Choose your hours

  [image]

**Result, affected both Inbox and Gmail:**

[image]

Comment: Now that Inbox is going away, has Google announced how to do this from Gmail alone? I can't find it.

Comment: Verified this is still a problem. Left complaints everywhere. If you have gsuite account, the most effective complaints are lodged in their private Gsuite feedback portal. https://www.cloudconnectcommunity.com/ccc/ls/community/g-suite/post/6311424599261184

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me -- I have different defaults in Inbox than in gmail.

Comment: The Google Keep answer, above, works following the removal of Inbox

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem, and found that changing the settings in the Gmail app on my iPhone updated it online too:

*Settings* → `Your Account` → *Snooze settings* and editing the times in there!

Nowhere to be seen on Gmail.com, but the settings pulled across.

Comment: Confirmed that worked for me. One quirk is that I wanted to change the "Later Today" time and that's mapped to the "Evening" time for some reason in the GMail iPhone settings.